# IF AND Statement with

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am working on data for products to see a certain difference in date (if the two dates are within 12 months) and if a `product type=F`.

Here is the formula I am using:

```
=IF(AND([@[MonthDifference]]>12,[@PRODUCTTYPE]="F"),"NO","YES")
```

The issue with this formula is that not every product is F. There are several product types. So my outcomes of the IF statement should be either: `Yes`, `No`, or `N/A` (for those that are not a product F type).

What am I missing from the formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For three different outputs you will need to nest the IF:

```
=IF([@PRODUCTTYPE]="F",IF([@[MonthDifference]]>12,"NO","YES"),"N/A")
```